# Gulp & TypeScript: Как правильно использовать интерфейс под другим именем без его экспорта в явном виде?

Tags: typescript, gulp, pug

TypeScript видит интерфейс `IGulpPlugins` из [@types/gulp-load-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/gulp-load-plugins) без экспорта в явном виде:

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as _gulpPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';

interface TestInterface extends IGulpPlugins {
  // ...
}
```

Мне нужно расширить этот интерфейс, чтобы воспользоваться препроцессором pug:

```
return gulp.src(globSelection)
        .pipe(gulpPlugins.pug())
        // ...
```

Интерфейс pug в [@types/pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pug) объявлен таким образом:

```
declare module 'pug' {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// Options https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#options ///
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    export interface Options {
      // ...
```

Options - имя, имеющее смысл лишь в определённом контексте, а потому его следует использовать как PugOption или что-то в этом роде. Как бы то ни было, интерфейс Options может присутствовать и в других библиотеках. Как правильно использовать интерфейс под другим именем в данном случае?

Comment: Он же в модуле. Он и так `pug.Options`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Благодарю Вас за ответ! Понял, как поступать в таких случаях...